# Get user scores from all google leaderboards

Tags: javascript, google-play-services, leaderboard

I have a game with multiple level, I setup a leaderboard for each level, now I want to get the score of a user for all levels.

I can get the score for one level using get API of google services, but I am having issue with multiple leaderboards.

I tried to do that with for loop but I am facing "Rate Limit Exceeded" issue (It seems to be due to the multiple fast requests the for loop is sending).

How can I get all scores?

Ps: I tried with setTimeout, always facing the same problem (Sometimes it retrieves datas but often not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `Rate Limit Exceeded` error, based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/quota), you will see errors in your callback handlers or listeners when your game exceeds its rate limit. To request for additional quota for your application, click the ***Request more*** link next to your app's quota entry in the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). Please be aware, however, that requests for additional games quota probably will not be honored unless your game is experiencing truly exceptional usage and is obeying these [best practices](https://developers.google.com/games/services/bestpractices#9_quota_and_rate_limiting).

Also, the suggested action from this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576682/how-to-load-scores-for-current-user-from-multiple-leaderboard-using-google-play) is to look at keeping a database of scores yourself, vs. using leaderboards as a datastore. Something like [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) might be more appropriate.